# Can't get Next 13 to NOT cache

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm having some issues with the Next 13 caching behaviour.

I have a page that shows a list of notifications. After I send a notification, I navigate to the list page, and the one I just sent is not in the list unless I refresh the page. I get that Next does a lot of caching by default, but that this can be turned off, which I'm trying to do.

Here is my API method:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { getNotifications } from '@/services/dataAccessService';

export const revalidate = 0;
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const notifications = await getNotifications();
  return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Hello world', notifications, count: notifications.length });
}
```

... and here is a snippet of my page:

```
export const revalidate = 0;
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

async function getNotifications() {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/getNotifications/`, { cache: 'no-store' });
  const data = await res.json();
  const notifications = data.notifications;
  return notifications;
}

const Page = async () => {
  const notifications = await getNotifications();

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-grow justify-center items-center'>
...
```

I'm using Next 13.4.19.